# Can't get this google map to work

Tags: javascript, xml, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

the only thing that shows up on the page is the beige background, the pan arrows and the zoom in/out bar but nothing else

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body,
      #map-canvas {
         height: 100%;
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC3lKBNm9jCGbUP8SH9j96S6AmUIRA2dPk">
  </script>
  <script type = "text/javascript" >

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://website.com/bustime/api/v1/getstops?key=555555&rt=CS&dir=Circ",false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

    var latitude = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("lat")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var longitude = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("lon")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

    function initialize(latitude, longitude) {

      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);
      var mapOptions = {
       zoom: 15,
       center: myLatlng
       }
       var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: myLatlng,
           map: map,

       });
     }

   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
   initialize(latitude, longitude);
});
 </script>
  </head>
  <body onLoad ="initialize(longitude, latitude)">
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

XML is as follows:

```
<bustime-response>
   <stop>
     <stpid>305</stpid>
     <stpnm>12TH</stpnm>
     <lat>33.996838209471</lat>
     <lon>-56.008665</lon>
   </stop>
</bustime-response>
```

I am at a loss with the xml parsing here and don't know what i may be missing. ACcording to the API Documentation I am using " the API is a web service which uses HTTP/1.1.

The map works if I directly put int he numbers for the lat/long, but otherwise it doesn't

EDIT: the errors I got after hitting Ctrl + shift + J are:

Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'http://trip.osu.edu/bustime/api/v1/getstops?key=Uw7ayuTAmaPDWnECG3khBLYd2&rt=CLS&dir=Circular'.(anonymous function) @ map2.html:27

http://trip.osu.edu/bustime/api/v1/getstops?key=Uw7ayuTAmaPDWnECG3khBLYd2&rt=CLS&dir=Circular. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

and I changed:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://trip.osu.edu/bustime/api/v1/getstops?key=Uw7ayuTAmaPDWnECG3khBLYd2&rt=CLS&dir=Circular",true);
```

Comment: This is probably because the website you are trying to load [link](http://website.com/bustime/api/v1/getstops?key=555555&rt=CS&dir=Circ) is giving a 404 - and hence the lat and long can't getting populated ?

Comment: I had to remove the link because it contained the api key: this is it http://trip.osu.edu/bustime/api/v1/getstops?key=Uw7ayuTAmaPDWnECG3khBLYd2&rt=CLS&dir=Circular

Comment: Uisng the new link you gave, it seems to work for me when I save it to a local "test.xml" and use that. When I use that directly with ajax - I get a CORS error. Are you getting a CORS error ? Could you open it in google-chrome and open the developer console with "Ctrl+Shift+J" and check the console tab if there are any errors specified there?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is that you are initializing the map twice. Once using the `google.maps.event.addDomListener` and using body's `onLoad ="initialize(longitude, latitude)"`

So, basically, your map loaded below the blank layer which didn't load correctly.

The recommended way to do it to avoid race conditions is `google.maps.event.addDomListener` ... when I remove the `onLoad ="initialize(longitude, latitude)"` it works for me.

Comment: for me if I remove the onLoad i get a blank white page.

Answer (score 0):

You are tryng to get a file:

`xmlhttp.open("GET","http://website.com/bustime/api/v1/getstops?key=555555&rt=CS&dir=Circ",false);`

with response http errore `301 Moved Permanently`